# Touch Bar doesn't show but I need F8

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, windows, vmware, touch-bar

I'm running a Windows Virtual Machine (VMWare) through an external hard drive, however, when I boot it, I gets the error, `Winload.efi is corrupted or missing` but it says I need to press F8 to change some settings for it to work.

The issue here is, I use a MacBook Pro with a Touch Bar and the Touch Bar isn't showing because there's no need when starting up the Windows VM.

I need to press F8 otherwise I can't repair the VM. Any ideas?

Comment: Very interesting question.  What if you press the `fn` key, do the function keys display?

Comment: It might be helpful to know which Virtualization software you are using, VMWare, Parallels or VirtualBox.

Comment: External keyboard?

Comment: @SteveChambers I'm using VMWare

Comment: @Allan That's the issue, nothing shows then.

Comment: @JBallin I just use my Laptop's keyboard.

Comment: Did you ensure that function keys are always displayed?  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207240

Comment: I’m suggesting you use an external keyboard

Comment: I did try @JBallin, nothing happened. it just reloaded the error message.

Comment: @Allan I meant nothing is displayed when the error comes. It's fine regularly.